# Computing expectation value of product of observables in PennyLane

Tags: programming, measurement, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, pennylane, quantum-neural-network

In PennyLane, the following circuit returns the expectation value of the `PauliZ` observable on qubit (wire) 1:

```
def my_quantum_function(x, y):
    qml.RZ(x, wires=0)
    qml.CNOT(wires=[0, 1])
    qml.RY(y, wires=1)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(1))
```

What if I instead wanted to return the expectation value of an operator $H = Z_1Z_2$ that acts on the first and the second qubit? How might I do that?

It is my understanding that qubits 1 and 2 are "correlated" because of the CNOT, so $\left\langle Z_1 Z_2 \right\rangle \neq \left\langle Z_1 \right\rangle \left\langle Z_2 \right\rangle$. Does this mean I have to define a custom operator? Or does `[qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(i)) for i in range(2)]` achieve what I want? Thanks for any help.

*Note*: The above example function was taken from the [PennyLane measurements documentation](https://pennylane.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction/measurements.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PennyLane supports measurements of tensor products of observable via the `@` operator, like so:

```
@qml.qnode(dev)
def my_quantum_function(x, y):
    qml.RZ(x, wires=0)
    qml.CNOT(wires=[0, 1])
    qml.RY(y, wires=1)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0) @ qml.PauliZ(1))
```

This should return the same result as the solution by [KAJ226](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15751/371) above, but will be slightly more efficient as it is avoiding creating a potentially large dense matrix.

There are some examples on [tensor observables](https://pennylane.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction/measurements.html#tensor-observables) in the PennyLane documentation.

Comment: Nice @Josh! I like this better. :)

Answer (score 4):

I *think* the following should work:

```
n_qubits = 2
Z = [ [1,0], [0,-1]]
ZZ = np.kron(Z,Z)

@qml.qnode(dev)
def circuit(params):
    qml.RY(params[0], wires=0)
    qml.CNOT(wires=[0, 1])
    qml.RY(params[1], wires=1)    
    return qml.expval(qml.Hermitian(ZZ, wires=[0, 1]))
```